# SEO for multiple counties and cities

Tags: seo, ranking, local-seo

I wanted to know the best practices for improving our SEO for service areas. We have a central office but cover all of Northern Virginia for our Web Design services and are currently only ranking in the areas surrounding our office address. How can I improve our SEO for multiple cities and counties?

I appreciate the advice! 
Thank you